# facebook graph API using libcurl/other libraries

Tags: c++, facebook, curl, libcurl

Is there any library using C++ or libcurl implementing Facebook graph API?

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to find a library that works, I think your best bet is to just write your own using libcurl.   That is the approach I am taking but I am struggling with how to handle the login process.   Good Luck!

Hector

Answer (score 0):

facebook has recently given a beta for device-based oauth 2 authentication. This should give everyone a method to use straight C (with the tos being complied with at least).

It's a closed beta, but it is news of something we will be using to do that.